# Oracle regex to find the special character in name field

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to filter out the names which have special characters.

**Requirement:**

1) Filter the names which have characters **other than** `a-zA-Z , space and forward slash(/)`.

**Regex being tried out:**

```
1) regexp_like (customername,'[^a-zA-Z[:space:]\/]'))
2) regexp_like (customername,'[^a-zA-Z \/]'))
```

The above two regex helps in finding the names with special characters like `? and dot(.)`

**For example:**

```
LEAL/JO?O

FRANCO/DIVALDO Sr.
```

But I couldn't figure out why some names(listed below) `with the allowed characters(a-zA-Z , space and forward slash(/)) also get retrieved.`

**For example:**

```
ESTEVES/MARIA INES

PEREZ/JOSE

DUTRA SILVA/LIGIA
```

Please help to figure out the mistake in the regex being used.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your regex #1 worked for me on 11g with the name data copied/pasted from this page. I wonder if you have non-printable control characters in the data? Try adding `[:cntrl:]` to the regex to catch control characters. P.S. the backslash is not needed before the slash when inside of a character class (square brackets).

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
      select 'LEAL/JO?O'          from dual union
      select 'FRANCO/DIVALDO Sr.' from dual union
      select 'ESTEVES/MARIA INES' from dual union
      select 'PEREZ/JOSE'         from dual union
      select 'DUTRA SILVA/LIGIA'  from dual
    )
    select *
    from tbl
    where regexp_like(name, '[^a-zA-Z[:space:][:cntrl:]/]');

NAME
------------------
FRANCO/DIVALDO Sr.
LEAL/JO?O

SQL>
```

If you can copy/paste this, run it and get the same results, then something is up with the data in your table.  Have a look at the data in HEX which will bring to light a previously hidden character perhaps.  Here's a simple example which shows the name "JOSE" in HEX.  Using one of the numerous ASCII charts out there like http://www.asciitable.com/ you can see there are no hidden characters:

```
SQL> select 'JOSE' as chr, rawtohex('JOSE') as hex from dual;

CHR  HEX
---- --------
JOSE 4A4F5345

SQL>
```

So, have a look at a name or two and see if you have any hidden characters.  If not, I suspect a conflicting characterset issue maybe.

Comment: @ Gary thanks for suggestion..tried the regex `regexp_like (customername,'[^a-zA-Z[:space:][:cntrl:]/]'))` . but still getting the non-expected values.

Comment: For the fun of it, copy and paste from this page my example from the "with" to the closing semi-colon and try it.  Does it work?  This was run in both Toad and Sql/Plus and worked for me.  If you can copy/paste and it works, then something is up with your data.  Maybe characterset related?  Anyway please try and post what happens.

Comment: you are correct. getting the below result `FRANCO/DIVALDO Sr.` and `LEAL/JO?O` . what could be the possible reason the other non-expected values getting fetched when the query executed as whole. any idea?

Comment: Ok so something is up with your data in the table.  I will update my post with a way to see it in hex, give me a minute....

Answer (score 0):

@gary_w has most of the bases well covered....

Here's my sql version of unix: `cat -vet MyFile`

```
select replace(regexp_replace(my_column,'[^[:print:]]', '!ACK!'),' ','.') as CAT_VET
from my_table
```

... all the non-printing characters become `!ACK!` and spaces become `.`  You still need to determine what the characters actually ARE, but it's useful to find the looney-toon characters in your data.

Also, `select dump(my_column) ...`  is another way to view the raw column values.

Comment: This is a great tip, run this first to see if non-printable characters are even an issue before using rawtohex() or dump() to see what those characters are.  Thanks Beege.